# Unión de 2 tablas

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas

Estoy intentando unir 2 tablas de Excel.

Primera tabla:

```
ORDEN DE COMPRA SKU
OC-P2-1 PRUEBA-BV2
OC-P2-2 PRUEBA-BV2
OC-P2-3 PRUEBA-BV2
OC-P3-1 PRUEBA-BV3
OC-P3-2 PRUEBA-BV3
OC-P3-3 PRUEBA-BV3
OC-P3-4 PRUEBA-BV3
OC-P3-5 PRUEBA-BV3
OC-P4-1 PRUEBA-BV4
OC-P4-2 PRUEBA-BV4
OC-P4-3 PRUEBA-BV4
OC-P4-4 PRUEBA-BV4
OC-P4-5 PRUEBA-BV4
OC-P4-6 PRUEBA-BV4
OC-P5-1 PRUEBA-BV5
OC-P5-2 PRUEBA-BV5
OC-P5-3 PRUEBA-BV5
OC-P5-4 PRUEBA-BV5
```

Segunda tabla:

```
numero_pedido   SKU
PRUEBA-12   PRUEBA-BV7
PRUEBA-11   PRUEBA-BV4
PRUEBA-10   PRUEBA-BV3
PRUEBA-9    PRUEBA-BV3
PRUEBA-8    PRUEBA-BV3
PRUEBA-7    PRUEBA-BV3
PRUEBA-6    PRUEBA-BV3
PRUEBA-5    PRUEBA-BV2
PRUEBA-4    PRUEBA-BV2
PRUEBA-3    PRUEBA-BV1
PRUEBA-2    PRUEBA-BV1
PRUEBA-1    PRUEBA-BV1
```

Intenté hacer un `merge` como se ve a continuación y un ciclado con doble condicional pero ninguno me funcionó debido a que cuando las uno me duplica los valores de la columna `numero_pedido`, en lugar de asignar solo una vez `prueba-10` y luego `prueba-9` me lo duplica `prueba-10` tantas veces como se repite el sku relacionado.

```
import pandas as pd

# Leer las tablas
tabla1 = pd.read_excel('prueba_1.xlsx', sheet_name='orden')
tabla2 = pd.read_excel('prueba_1.xlsx', sheet_name='pedido')


# Hacer la unión de las tablas de manera que se incluyan todas las filas de ambas tablas
tabla_unida = pd.merge(tabla1, tabla2, on="SKU", how="outer", suffixes=("_1", "_2"))

# Mostrar el resultado
print(tabla_unida)
tabla_unida.to_excel('prueba_2.xlsx')
```

Al final obtengo esto

```
    ORDEN DE COMPRA SKU numero_pedido
0   OC-P2-1 PRUEBA-BV2  PRUEBA-5
2   OC-P2-2 PRUEBA-BV2  PRUEBA-5
4   OC-P2-3 PRUEBA-BV2  PRUEBA-5
6   OC-P3-1 PRUEBA-BV3  PRUEBA-10
11  OC-P3-2 PRUEBA-BV3  PRUEBA-10
16  OC-P3-3 PRUEBA-BV3  PRUEBA-10
21  OC-P3-4 PRUEBA-BV3  PRUEBA-10
26  OC-P3-5 PRUEBA-BV3  PRUEBA-10
31  OC-P4-1 PRUEBA-BV4  PRUEBA-11
32  OC-P4-2 PRUEBA-BV4  PRUEBA-11
33  OC-P4-3 PRUEBA-BV4  PRUEBA-11
34  OC-P4-4 PRUEBA-BV4  PRUEBA-11
35  OC-P4-5 PRUEBA-BV4  PRUEBA-11
36  OC-P4-6 PRUEBA-BV4  PRUEBA-11
37  OC-P5-1 PRUEBA-BV5  
38  OC-P5-2 PRUEBA-BV5  
39  OC-P5-3 PRUEBA-BV5  
40  OC-P5-4 PRUEBA-BV5
```

La ultima columna me duplica los datos.

Y quiero llegar a este resultado

```
    orden_compra    sku         numero_pedido
1                   PRUEBA-BV1  PRUEBA-1
2   OC-P3-4         PRUEBA-BV3  PRUEBA-10
3   OC-P4-1         PRUEBA-BV4  PRUEBA-11
4                   PRUEBA-BV7  PRUEBA-12
5                   PRUEBA-BV1  PRUEBA-2
6                   PRUEBA-BV1  PRUEBA-3
7   OC-P2-3         PRUEBA-BV2  PRUEBA-4
8   OC-P2-1         PRUEBA-BV2  PRUEBA-5
9   OC-P3-3         PRUEBA-BV3  PRUEBA-6
10  OC-P3-1         PRUEBA-BV3  PRUEBA-7
11  OC-P3-5         PRUEBA-BV3  PRUEBA-8
12  OC-P3-2         PRUEBA-BV3  PRUEBA-9
13  OC-P5-1         PRUEBA-BV5
```

Ya sea con 2 columnas o agregando mas columnas, de antemano gracias.

Comment: Buen día, por favor oprime [edit] y agrega un ejemplo del resultado que obtienes actualmente y el resultado deseado para que entendamos mejor el problema.

Comment: hola ya añadi lo que obtengo al final

Comment: El resultado que te devuelve el comando `pd.merge` es el correcto y esperado. Si no añades una tabla con el resultado que tú quieres obtener, no podemos saber en qué punto estás fallando. El merge te devuelve "duplicados" porque la `tabla1` tiene `SKU` repetidos varias veces, por lo que cada fila distinta con mismo `SKU` debe aparecer reflejada.